# Passing additional arguments to the jacobian in scipy.optimize.root

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I am solving large systems of equations, but have access to the jacobian matrix.

I decided to uses scipy.optimize.root (open to other suggestions), where I can pass the jacobian as an additional callable. The only problem is that my jacobian contains additional constants eg.

For this example y, z needs to be solved and k is a constant

```
import scipy.optimize

def fun(x, k):
    [y, z]= x

    return [k*y**2 + z**2 - 25, k*z*y ]

def jacobian(x, k):
    [y, z] = x

    j = [[2*k*y, 2*z],
         [  k*z, k*y]]

    return j

solution = scipy.optimize.root(fun, [x1, x2], jaco=(jacobian, value_for_k))
```

Comment: you can inject a k using `functools.partial`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 6):

Use `root(..., args=(value,))` to find the root of `fun(x,value)==0` at fixed `value`. Note that `args` must be a tuple even if a single-element one.