# passing in initial/boundary conditions for a function in scipy.optimize.root as the args argument

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve a non linear system. Here is the code for a toy problem.

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import scipy

def flat(x):
    ''' flattens a shallow list
        ex: [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]] ----> flattens to [1,2,3,4,5]
        numpy flatten does not work on lists.
    '''
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return [a for i in x for a in flat(i)]
    else:
        return [x]


def func(X):
    '''setups the matrix dynamic equation and the set of constraints
    '''
    A = [[0,1,0,1],[2,1,0,4],[1,4,1,3],[3, 2, 1,0]]
    A1 = [[1,0,1,-1], [0,-1,2,1],[1,2,0,1],[1,2,0,-2]]
    x = X[:-1]
    alpha = X[-1]
    x0 = [1,2,3,4]
    y = x - x0
    # x[0] = 0.5
    # x[3] = 0.3
    dyneqn = np.dot(A,y) + alpha * np.dot(A1,x)
    cons = (1/2.0)*np.dot(x.T,np.dot(A1,x)) + np.dot([-1,1,2,-3], x) + 0.5
    return flat([dyneqn, cons])

sol = scipy.optimize.root(func,[1,-1,2,0,-1])
sol.x
```

**Problem Statement**

The argument `X` of the objective function `f` has five unknowns that we are solving for. I want to set the first parameter, i.e., `X[0]=0.5`and the fourth  parameter i.e., `X[3] = 0.3` and solve for the remaining `3 unknowns`. Let us assume for simplicity that such a solution exists and my initial guess is somehow a good one.

**Attempt**:

I know I should probably pass these arguments to the `args=()` argument in `scipy.optimize.root`. I tried setting

```
args = (X[0]=0.5, X[3]=0.3)
init_guess = [0.5,-1,2,0.3,-1]
scipy.optimize.root(func,init_guess, args=args)
```

This is obviously wrong.

**Question?** How can I fix this?.

*Note: I added the flat function so that the code is self contained. It has nothing to do with this question*.

Comment: what do you expect from `(X[0]=0.5, X[3]=0.3)`?

Comment: if i understood correctly your `flat` function is the same as `list` from result of [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: I just want to concatenate `dyneqn`and `cons` as a single array. `flat` just does that.

Comment: There is probably a nicer way to write this problem without the flat function. But that is not my question.

Comment: Are you sure `root` is the function you should use? It solves a system of equations exactly, which means the number of equations must be equal to the number of free parameters. From the problem statement it seems like `minimize` might be more appropriate. hpaulj's answer applies to that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example I reconstruct that you want to solve for the second and third component of some vector `x` as well as the parameter `alpha`. With the `args` keyword of [`scipy.optmize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) that would look something like

```
def func(x_solve, x0, x3):
    #x_solve.size should be 3 
    x = np.empty(4)
    x[0], x[3] = x0, x3
    x[1:3] = x_solve[:2]
    alpha = x_solve[2]
    ...

scipy.optimize.root(func, [-1,2,-1], args=(.5, .3))
```

As Azat and kazemakase pointed out, I'm also not sure if you actually want to use `root`, but the usage of [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) is pretty much the same.

**Edit:** It should be possible to have a flexible set of fixed variables by using a dictionary as an additional argument which specifies those:

```
def func(x_solve, fixed):
    x = x_solve[:-1] # last value is alpha
    for idx in fixed.keys(): # overwrite fixed entries
        x[idx] = fixed[idx]
    alpha = x_solve[-1]

# fixed variables, key is the index
fixed_vars = {0:.5, 3:.3}

# find roots
scipy.optimize.root(func, 
                    [.5, -1, 2, .3, -1], 
                    args=(fixed_vars,))
```

That way, when the optimizer in `root` numerically evaluates the Jacobian it obtains zero for the fixed variables and should therefore leave those invariant. However, that might lead to complications in the convergence of the algorithm.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this without re-arranging the arguments of the function?. The reason is I will have to do the same calculation for different permutations of `setting parameters to constants`. For example in a second case I will have to set `x0=0.5` and solve for the rest of the parameters x1, x2, x3, alpha

Comment: I added a solution that would _probably_ work. It's not very nice though.

Comment: I will try this out. I will actually provide the analytical Jacobian for the solver just to make its life easier and of course to make it faster. In my experience providing the Jacobian just makes everything work out nicely.

Comment: Yes, thats usually a good Idea. Just mind that you adapt it similarly such that it returns zero for all partial derivatives of variables in the `fixed` dictionary.

Comment: I have a question to ask regarding your suggestion to use minimize. I can only use minimize on a scaler valued function, correct?. But my function is vector valued. `f(X) = 0` means zero vector on the right hand side. How can I use minimize on a vector valued function?. It doesn't make sense to me. Can you clarify?

Comment: In the last line shouldn't it be `args = ((fixed,))`?

Comment: You are correct that it is not straight forward to formulate your problem as a minimization. The thing is that your version doesn't have a unique minimum, so when `root` finds a solution, it is not really clear which one it you have. My guess would be that you can reformulate it in a different way such that you get a more predictable behavior by using `minimize` with a more clever formulation. However, if you just need SOME solution and just don't care about the rest your probably fine.

Comment: No, that 1st line should be correct like that. The second parentheses `)` close the function, i.e. the `scipy.optimize.root(...` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Typically with `scipy` functions like root, minimize, etc

```
root(func, x0, args=(a, b, c, ...))
```

requires a `func` that accepts:

```
func(x0, a, b, c, ...)
    # do something those arguments
    return value
```

`x0` is the value that `root` varies, `a,b,c` are `args` value that are passed unchanged to your function.  Depending of the problem `x0` may be an array.  The nature of the `args` is entirely up to you.

Comment: I was trying to do what  this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37202169/6431877 suggested. So If I understand you correctly I will have to re-write my function to make this work?. Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: In the link, the distinction between `x` and `k` is pretty clear.  `k` is fixed, `x` varies.  You split `X` into `x` and `alpha`.  Are you searching for a value of `x` that returns a 0 value?

Comment: Well I am searching for an `X` value for which `func(X) = 0` but some values of `X` are fixed. specifically the first and the second to last variables.

Comment: `X = [x0, x1, x2, x3, alpha]` and `x0` and `x3` does not vary and I want to solve `f(X) = 0` for the rest.

Comment: So isn't my answer below doing what you want? It does keep `x0` and `x3` constant. What do you mean by `f(x) =0`? Your `func` is a vector valued function. Do you expect all entries to be zero?